# Seeing all the system calls that were made by a Java program

Tags: java, linux, system-calls

How can I see which system calls my Java program is making? Is there a tool that will do this on Linux?

Comment: Could you use `strace java your_program`?

Comment: I tried it and it worked.Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace):

```
strace -f java your_program
```

or

```
strace -f -p <pid of your java program>
```

Answer (score 17):

Use strace. But there is is trick for my case. Option `-f` is needed and is the same as `--follow-forks`. For example, the following code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("XXX");    
    }
}
```

After running `javac Foo.java` to compile it, `strace java Foo 2>&1 | grep write` print nothing. But `strace -f java Foo 2>&1 | grep write` prints:

```
[pid 11655] write(3, "0x63", 4)         = 4
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(3, "\0", 1)           = 1
[pid 11655] write(1, "XXX", 3XXX)          = 3
[pid 11655] write(1, "\n", 1
```

`[pid 11655] write(1, "XXX", 3XXX)          = 3` shows the system call made for `System.out.println("XXX")`.

Answer (score 1):

see ltrace http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace

Comment: ptrace might be more useful in this case

Comment: @MikeKwan `ltrace` is for library function calls and `ptrace` is to examine other process' memory. `strace` is the one for system calls.