# Font extension doesn't work for OTF font - JasperReports 4.7.1

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, opentype

I followed all the examples I could find on the internet to embed an *OTF* font into the generated PDF but it doesn't work. I created a font extension .jar using *iReport* (I have also created a maven jar for fonts manually) but it doesn't work with *OTF* fonts. I also made sure that the *jasper-fonts-extension.jar* is on the classpath. I know it, because when I replace this font with some other *TTF* fonts, it just works.

I am running on -

```
Jasper Reports & iReport Version : 4.7.1
Oracle Java SDK 7
Ubuntu 12.04
```

The font I am trying to embed in the *PDF* - Myraid Pro (*OTF*)

My fonts.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
   <fontFamily name="Myriad Pro">
   <normal><![CDATA[fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf]]></normal>
   <bold><![CDATA[fonts/MYRIADPRO-BOLD.OTF]]></bold>
   <italic><![CDATA[fonts/MYRIADPRO-CONDIT.OTF]]></italic>
   <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/MYRIADPRO-BOLDIT.OTF]]></boldItalic>
   <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>
   <fontFamily name="Myriad Pro Lite">
      <normal><![CDATA[fonts/MYRIADPRO-COND.OTF]]></normal>
      <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

This worked with other *TTF* fonts but when I switch to MyraidPro fonts, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:122)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:464)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:861)
at com.qedrix.formbuilder.pojo.JsonForm.main(JsonForm.java:141)
```

Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf' is not available to the JVM.

I also followed the steps given in the following link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport)

If this is something to do with the *OTF* fonts, I wonder why this wont work when exporting a *PDF* in *Java* while it works in *iReport's* preview mode?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151562/jasperreports-how-to-add-font-not-in-the-application-classpath/55600533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a little bug in JasperReports. The entry in "fonts.xml"

`<normal><ttf>fonts/OfficinaSansStd-Book.otf</ttf></normal>`

throws the exception. If you RENAME your font file and change the entry to

`<normal><ttf>fonts/OfficinaSansStd-Book.ttf</ttf></normal>`

it works fine with me.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo after renaming OTF to TTF worked in java and ireport 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to follow the following answer to get those fonts working in a PDF output.  [Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport)

Also you may want to follow what file calls the app is using to find the font.  I recommend strace on linux.

Comment: Thanks. I have followed that link already ( i mentioned that in my post at the end). This didn't help. I hear that Java has issues processing otf fonts with Adobe 1 encoding; but I cannot confirm. You last statement - can you explain a bit more on that please?

Comment: Right, on most OS'es you can log the file activity to find out what file calls an application is doing.  Most likely Java is traversing a known set of paths to find that fontname/filename. strace is such a command that on linux will log what an app is doing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384850/seeing-all-the-system-calls-that-were-made-by-a-java-program